# Run powershell script as microservice

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, automation, microservices

Is it possible to make my powershell script, run as a microservice?

```
Param(
    $a,
    $b
)

$x = [int]$a + [int]$b

echo $x
```

Comment: A microservice in what way?

Comment: What's a microservice, exactly? In particular in the context of Windows scripting.

Comment: I want to run my script, as an service accepting http requests of type HTTP GET on address http://localhost:port/sum?a=1&b=2, and respond with the content 3.

Comment: Very strange idea, unless this is just for experimentation / playing with some concepts. See this: http://www.poshserver.net/ however.

Comment: Powershell can run an HTTP server. You should start researching the topic and decide which of the various options you like. If you have decided on an option and have a specific question, you are welcome to ask it. A quick search turned up this Gist: https://gist.github.com/wagnerandrade/5424431, but there are more examples to get you started.

Comment: i disagree, running web server in a Powershell is hell of a mess + doesnt help with distributing load and stuff like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should take a look at Azure Functions, they achieve exactly that what you want and they support PowerShell/

https://david-obrien.net/2016/07/azure-functions-PowerShell/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/